# What is the best practice of MariaDB Encryption?

Tags: encryption, mariadb

I have tried to deploy encryption system with MariaDB 5.5.30.

But it is not easy to build up with encryption functions.

https://kb.askmonty.org/en/encryption-functions/

So, I would like to buy some encryption tools.
As I searched, file-level encryption can be deployed.
It is well organised, but too expensive.

Is there any good practice or tools for MariaDB encryption?

p.s. I know MariaDB is similar with MySQL, but sometimes it doesn't work like MySQL.

Comment: I think mydiamo is useful for you. I am using it since couple of years ago. Not freeware, but storng

Answer (score 1):

Nuga,

First of all, how much information do you want to encrypt?

If you want to encrypt almost every databases or columns, there is no difference between file-level encryption and another type encryption tools.
In that case, you can find many file-level encryption tools like Gazzang's nZcrypt.
http://www.gazzang.com/products/zncrypt

However, if you want to encrypt only few columns, I would like you to find Cell-level encryption or Column-level encryption tools.
As I know in SQL Server, its' own encryption function supports Cell-level encryption, but I am not sure whether Cell-level encryption tools exists in MariaDB.

Recently, I have found Column-Level encryption software, MyDiamo.

http://www.mydiamo.com

How about you check those tools first?